# MutationSummary - observe a specific attribute on an element, and execute some code after that attribute gets a specific value

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I've written a Greasemonkey [userscript](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/14036-kat-add-approve-all-and-approve-selected-buttons-to-feedback-popup) for kat.cr that adds a few extra buttons  inside the 'Torrents awaiting feedback' popup.

The procedure is this: *(provided that you have login and that you have some downloaded some torrents that "await feedback")*:
after you click the FEEDBACK button, the 'Torrents awaiting feedback' popup appears,
containing the torrents that await feedback,
i.e. the `style.display` attribute of e.g. the element `#fancybox-wrap` 
becomes from `none` to `block` *(as I've noticed in Firefox Inspector)*.

I currently use `setTimeout` to insert delay until the popup appears.

I want to improve the script.
So, I want to use  [MutationSummary](https://github.com/rafaelw/mutation-summary/blob/master/APIReference.md) *(as a more practical solution to MutationObserver)*
in order to monitor the change in the attribute `style.display` on the above element,
and add my extra buttons after that change occurs.

My code's structure is like this:

```
document.querySelector('.showFeedback > a').addEventListener('click', function () {

  var observer = new MutationSummary({
    callback: myF,
    queries: [
      {
        element: '#fancybox-wrap',
        elementAttributes: 'style.display'
      }
    ]
  });

  function myF(muteSummaries) {
    var mSummary = muteSummaries[0];
    mSummary.valueChanged.forEach(function(changeEl) {
      console.log('Attribute changed'); // Here I would add my code of inserting the extra buttons
    }      

});
```

Unfortunately the `console.log` is not executed.
*Note that if I change `elementAttributes: 'style.display'` to `elementAttributes: 'style'`

then I get `TypeError: mSummary.valueChanged is undefined` in Browser Console.*
How can I fix this?

---

Here is a working version of the code using MutationObserver:

```
document.querySelector('.showFeedback > a').addEventListener('click', function() {

    var target1 = document.querySelector('#fancybox-wrap');

    var observer1 = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            if (document.querySelector('#fancybox-wrap').style.display == 'block') {
                console.log('Attribute changed');
            }
        });
    });

    var config = {
        attributes: true,
        childList: true,
        characterData: true
    };

    observer1.observe(target1, config);

});
```

Comment: It's probable that the `#fancybox-wrap` element doesn't exist until it's displayed for the first time, in which case you'll have to wait for it to appear, for example by watching child list mutations of its parent or higher.

Comment: No, that's not the case. The `#fancybox-wrap` element *(as well as the rest elements starting with `fancybox-`)* exists even before I click the FEEDBACK button or when there are currently no torrents awaiting feedback. Just open https://kat.cr/ , login, and then search in inspector for `#fancybox-wrap`

Comment: Never used that wrapper (I think MutationObserver is simple by itself) but `style.display` is an invalid attribute name. Use `style`. Or `['style']` (the original MutationObserver expects an array of strings).

Comment: @wOxxOm: I've just edited the question, modifying the initial code and adding a working version using MutationObserver. *Note that if I change `elementAttributes: 'style.display'` to `elementAttributes: 'style'`
then I get `TypeError: mSummary.valueChanged is undefined` in Browser Console.* *(with `elementAttributes: 'style.display'` there's no errorrs)*

Comment: Let someone else comment on `MutationSummary`. As for your new code, there's no need for a loop if you remove the irrelevant `characterData` and `childList` and just use `attributes: true, attributeFilter: ['style']` in config. You can also reuse `mutations[0].target` instead of another `querySelector`. http://pastie.org/private/4yfqzulpwzebbkeg7omq5w