# insertBefore (enclosed in addEventListener "click" and called via MutationObserver on element attribute value change) is executed multiple times

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, mutation-observers

*This is a continuance to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010044/mutationsummary-observe-a-specific-attribute-on-an-element-and-execute-some-c).*

I've written a Greasemonkey [userscript](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/14036-kat-add-approve-all-and-approve-selected-buttons-to-feedback-popup) for kat.cr that adds a few extra buttons  inside the 'Torrents awaiting feedback' popup.

---

The procedure is this: *(provided that you have login and that you have some downloaded some torrents that "await feedback")*:
after you click the FEEDBACK button, the 'Torrents awaiting feedback' popup appears,
containing the torrents that await feedback,
i.e. the `style.display` attribute of e.g. the element `#fancybox-wrap` 
becomes from `none` to `block` *(as I've noticed in Firefox Inspector)*.

---

I want to improve the script, so, I'm trying to use `MutationObserver`
in order to monitor the change in the attribute `style.display` on the above element,  and add my extra buttons after that change occurs.

My code is like this:

```
document.querySelector('.showFeedback > a').addEventListener('click', function() {


    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        if (mutations[0].target.style.display == 'block') {
            var parentElement = document.querySelector('div.buttonsline:nth-child(10)');
            var theFirstChild = parentElement.firstChild;
            var button = document.createElement('BUTTON');
            parentElement.insertBefore(button, theFirstChild);
            button.id = 'mybutton1';
            button.innerHTML = 'APPROVE SELECTED';
            document.querySelector('#mybutton1').className = 'siteButton bigButton';
        }
    }).observe(
        document.querySelector('#fancybox-wrap'), {
            attributes: true,
            attributeFilter: ['style']
        }
    );


});
```

The problem is that the button is added multiple times, instead of 1.
Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently that element's style is changed for other properties, not only `display`.

Check whether the old `display` value wasn't `block` (requires `attributeOldValue` parameter):

```
new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    if (mutations[0].target.style.display == 'block' && 
        !mutations[0].oldValue.match(/display:\s*block/)) {
        ...............
    }
}).observe(document.querySelector('#fancybox-wrap'), {
    attributeOldValue: true,
    attributeFilter: ['style']
});
```

or look at the button id:

```
if (mutations[0].target.style.display == 'block' && 
    !document.querySelector('#mybutton1')) {
```

or disconnect the observer after the first successful run:

```
new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    if (mutations[0].target.style.display == 'block') {
        observer.disconnect();
        ...........
    }
})...........
```

Also there's no need for `var observer =` because it's passed as a parameter to the callback.

Comment: You'd need to pass the `.observe` call `attributeOldValue: true` for the first approach to work.